# Why can shared libraries be located as one user, but not as another?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries

I have compiled a Qt application that needs to be run as another user. However, it is unable to load the Qt shared libraries when it is run as that user:

```
~/MyApp/src $ sudo -u otherUser ./MyApp
./MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Doing an `ldd` as `otherUser`, we see the expected:

```
~/MyApp/src $ sudo -u otherUser ldd ./MyApp
libQtGui.so.4 => not found
```

However, when I do an `ldd` as myself, I can find the `libQtGui.so.4` shared library just fine.

```
~/MyApp/src $ ldd ./MyApp
libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00002b97a4e1a000)
libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00002b97a5bf1000)
```

Why can't `otherUser` find the shared libraries? What do I need to do to make `MyApp` executable by `otherUser`?

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH appears to be empty for both users:

```
~/MyApp/src $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

~/MyApp/src $ sudo -u otherUser echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

~/MyApp/src $
```

Comment: Can `otherUser` access the shared library files?

Comment: Is there a different in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` between the users?

Comment: Doesn't `./Myapp`, when executed from `~/MyApp/src`, translate to `~/MyApp/src/Myapp` ?

Comment: @DavidBrown, yes, I did a `chmod -R 777 /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Almost, the A is capitalized. So the application exists at ~/MyApp/src/MyApp

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I have updated my question with that information.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Be interested to see what the answer is (it's not some weird link issue - where the .so.4 is a link to some other file that hasn't got the right permissions?)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Hmm, nope. It is a link to another file, but that file has the same permissions. Ugh.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u otherUser ls /usr/local/Trolltech/...`

Comment: @MatsPetersson - Finally figured it out. Everything under `Trolltech` had correct permissions, but `Trolltech` itself didn't have the correct permissions accessible to `otherUser`. *facepalm*

Comment: You wouldn't be the first one making that mistake - and probably not the last either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire directory path leading to the shared libraries must be accessible by `otherUser`.  Check all the folders in the path:

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib/
```

`otherUser` should have access to `usr`, `local`, `Trolltech`, `Qt-4.8.5`, and `lib`.

In my specific case when I had this problem, the `Trolltech` directory was not accessible to `otherUser`.

Answer (score -1):

Check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You may find that your user has a different path than for the other user. You may need to set (or update) this variable for the user that can't find the library.